# On Android, is there any way to detect if a ScrollView has it's scroll bar activated?

Tags: android, scrollview

Basically, I want to detect if the data content inside a ScrollView is larger then the containing window (meaning that the scroll view would have to be scrolled up or down to be able to view all the information). I need to make a slight change in the layout at runtime if that view can't fit on the screen (and would need to be scrolled). So, short of writing my own class that extends ScrollView, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for `scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);`?

Comment: you can use validations for that, why make a custom scrollview for that.

Comment: No, I don't need to set the scroll bar to be always shown. I just need to detect when it's shown. And what do you mean by validations?

Comment: You can check this: `boolean isScrollable = scrollView.getHeight() < childHeight + scrollView.getPaddingTop() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();` and then use If statement to do whatever you want to, knowing if it's scrolling or not.

Comment: I'll see if that works

Comment: Ok, that works for most of what I need, but is there a way to detect when the scrollbar becomes active? (e.g. if they click on an an EditText field, and the keyboard comes up, the view becomes smaller, and scrollbars appear)

Comment: When you use adjustPan then window will always ajdust itself to show the focused view eg Edittext and then the scrolling is always active.

Comment: that's not true --  if the windows was small enough, it could fit above the keyboard without having to enabling scrolling in the ScrollView

Comment: Depends on device actually. It might show all in tabs.  Btw, why do you want to know if it's active or not while the keyboard is active?

Comment: It's for layout purposes. If the data view is to big, I'm putting a separator between the data in the popup window and the button bar at the bottom. If not, the separator is hidden. But your original comment is good enough to answer my question. Just post it as an answer, please, and I'll accept it.